# Prove (A-B) $\approx$ (C-D)

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let A,B C,D be finite. Given A$\approx$ B
and C$\approx$ D and C$\subset$A and
D$\subset$ B Prove (A-C)$\approx$ (B-D)

7.10 Theorem If A ≈ B and C ≈ D, then A × C ≈ B × D.

Attempted proof

By 7.10 AxC->BxD so there exists a bijection function f:AxC->BxD  s.t f$_{[c]}$:C$\mapsto$ A be injective
then there exists a surjective
function g:BxD->AxC and g$_{[d]}:$D$\mapsto$B
D(f)=AxC R(f)=BxD
Define a mapping on this relation
A ⊂B & C⊂D->A/C⊂B/D

Then?

I had  an idea to find a mapping from A to B and a
complement map from C to D,if this makes any sense

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe prove it by induction on $\#C$?

Comment: Not introduced to cardinals yet